package installed but not detected by CMake
The dependency are already installed but still not being detected by Cmake build.
For example Package 'hyprcursor', required by 'virtual:world', not found
and other package like libliftoff, libdisplay-info also same
but,
rpm -ql hyprcursor  
/usr/bin/hyprcursor-util
/usr/lib/.build-id
/usr/lib/.build-id/32
/usr/lib/.build-id/32/05c1dffee89b3e4e49d035de4b5c2ff8f7a82d
/usr/lib/.build-id/e7
/usr/lib/.build-id/e7/c60306a54118d42cee281b6d1044d2cd681537
/usr/lib64/libhyprcursor.so.0
/usr/lib64/libhyprcursor.so.0.1.8
/usr/share/doc/hyprcursor
/usr/share/doc/hyprcursor/README.md
/usr/share/licenses/hyprcursor
/usr/share/licenses/hyprcursor/LICENSE

But building the package from source it works
OS: fedora 39

Do you need hyprcursor-dev?

You haven't installed the hyprcursor development package.
As a runtime client of library libfooyou need rpm foo-<version> installed. As a developer wanting to compile and link against libfoo you need
rpm foo-devel-<version> installed, to get the header files, static library, package-configuration file, all that good stuff.

Need to install -devel packages for development purposes
like
sudo dnf install <package>-devel

can search if -devel package is present
sudo dnf search <package>

